# customInput not returning the selected date in react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am trying to open the [react-datepicker](/questions/tagged/react-datepicker) on the click of an icon. For that, I am using `customInput` parameter. The [react-datepicker](/questions/tagged/react-datepicker) is getting opened on the click of the icon, but the `onChange` handler is not getting the selected date. Here is my code:

```
<div className="date-icon">
    <DatePicker
        id="date-picker"
        dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        showMonthDropdown
        onChange={this.handleDateChange.bind(this)}
        customInput={<img src="/img/cal.svg" alt=""/>}
        //includeDates={this.state.activityDates}
    />
    <br/>
 </div>
```

And here is the handleDateChange function

```
handleDateChange(date, event){
    console.log(document.getElementById("date-picker").value)
}
```

I am getting `undefined` on console log.

When I remove that `customInput` parameter, then the date gets printed in the console as expected.

Comment: The default input is an `input` element, which has a `value`. Your custom input `<img src="/img/cal.svg" alt=""/>` is not an `input` element, and has no `value`. Why don't you put the date in state instead of trying to access it on the DOM element?

Comment: Can you tell me how? Because the "date" parameter in the handleDateChange is a "moment" object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default input is an `input` element, which has a `value`. Your custom input `<img src="/img/cal.svg" alt=""/>` is not an input element, and has no `value`.

You could instead store the moment given to you in the `onChange` handler and store that in state and use that instead.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { selectedDate: moment() };

  handleDateChange = m => {
    this.setState({ selectedDate: m });
    console.log(m.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        id="date-picker"
        dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
        selected={this.state.selectedDate}
        showMonthDropdown
        onChange={this.handleDateChange}
        customInput={<img src="/img/cal.svg" alt=""/>}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the date of format "YYYY-MM-DD" from the moment. I really don't need the moment to be store. Can you please suggest a way?

Comment: @ApurvG The date picker still needs the moment internally, so it's best to store that in state. I updated the answer with how you can get the date in that format.